# What's calling my shell scripts?

Tags: debian, shell, cron

i've been given the task to have a pals server download a news audio file at 4 given times over the weekend and put them into his webs audio directory.

Don't stone me, here's what i came up with:

```
#/bin/bash

cd /usr/bin/autonews
wget --user=XXX --password='XXX' ftp://XXX.XXX.XXX/news.mp3
mv -v /usr/bin/autonews/news.mp3 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/A_Audio/01_News/News_09.mp3
chown -v web1:client1 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/A_Audio/01_News/News_09.mp3
```

There are four of those, each for the time and specific filename to use at the given time. These are called via cron

```
MAILTO="XXX"
51 11 * * 6 /usr/bin/autonews/sa_11-51
MAILTO="XXX"
51 17 * * 6 /usr/bin/autonews/sa_17-51
MAILTO="XXXX"
51 5 * * 0 /usr/bin/autonews/so_5-51
MAILTO="XXX"
51 11 * * 0 /usr/bin/autonews/so_11-51
```

When testing it seemed to work ok. Over night the directory filled up with files

```
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4294986 Dez 12 05:51 News_06.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4294986 Dez 12 06:51 News_07.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4294986 Dez 12 07:51 News_08.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4294986 Dez 12 11:12 News_09.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4252541 Dez  8 17:33 News_18.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4294986 Dez 11 18:51 News_19.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4294986 Dez 11 19:51 News_20.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4294986 Dez 11 20:51 News_21.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4294986 Dez 11 21:51 News_22.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 web1 client1 4294986 Dez 11 22:51 News_23.mp3
```

It seems the files weren't created via cron, as there are no mails coming in.
What could be running the scripts every hour and change the number in the file names sequentially, as i'm quite sure the scripts don't leave room for creativity concerning the file names?
I've been running a full tartarus backup over night, but that shouldn't trigger shell scripts, or does it? Where do i start to look?
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Does your server have mail sending set up in the first place?

Comment: Yes it has. Thanks for your time and apologies... syslog is my friend.

Comment: The 'pal' in question uploaded these files via a homemade script and it had nothing to do with me and my files. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found via syslog that the files weren't created by my scripts, but uploaded by my 'pal' (who asked me to investigate the strange files in the first place) :D
The human factor...